# Error while accessing jsonObject in couchbase

Tags: java, json, couchbase

I'm having this JSON as a couchbase document :

```
{
  "document": [
    {
      "Value 1": 36.29,
      "Date 1": 1495144800000,
      "Date 2": 1495144800000,
      "Date 3": 1495144800000,
      "Value 2": "5444158076"
    }
  ],
  "exception": null
}
```

What I want to do is to get the Date 1, Date 2 and Date 3 then change them (with JAVA).

I'm using `doc.content().getString(jsonKey);` to get, but it only work at the first level of the JSON (i can only get the exception value).

I don't know if I can ask at the same question, but if you also can help me with updating some value in a JSONArray (modify the Date 1/2/3 values) it would be great.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting the array associated with "document" key (jsonKey should be "document" and then get the map associated with the first element in the array.